# solution to the equation $y'' +2y' -3y =4x-5e^{2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $y_1(x)= -x/3 -2/9$ is a solution of the equation $y''+2y'-3y=x$
and $y_2(x) = (e^{2x})/5$ is a solution to the equation $y''+2y'-3y=e^{2x}$, I am supposed to find a solution of  $y'' +2y' -3y =4x-5e^{2x}$.  How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $4y_1(x)-5y_2(x)$ is a **particular** solution of the DE.

Add to this the **general** solution of the homogeneous DE $y''+2y'-3y=0$.

**Remark:** For the homogeneous DE, the characteristic equation is $r^2+2r-3=0$, which has the solutions $r=-3$ and $r=1$. Thus the general solution of the homogeneous DE is $Ae^{-3x}+Be^{x}$.

The entire calculation is a tribute to the power of *linearity*.